# Does the fever curing mantra given by Dvivida found elsewhere? Is it in a mantra group family? Are any other mantras supposed to be written?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, mantras, ayurveda, vanaras

In [Chapter 27](https://cloudup.com/cws97nPY2uD) of the Kalki Purāṇa a short mantra is written by Dvivida for curing Lakṣmaṇa of a fever:

> समुद्रस्योतरे तीरे
> द्विविदो नाम वानरः
>
> Samudrasyotare tīre
> Dvivido nāma Vānaraḥ

This is an odd story. This mantra seems important, but I don't know of another instance of this appearing. It is also written as opposed to spoken and doesn't seem to be in a mantra family like the Gayatri mantras. Does anyone at least know its mantra family?

Comment: Not all mantras are required to be of the format of Gayatri. This is also a mantra. The Shabara mantras which just look like some meaningless sentences are also mantras.

Comment: @Rickross Well, yes. I'm wondering if it is a mantra family though e.g. through following syllable rules.

Comment: Not all mantras are required to be of the format of Gayatri. This is also a mantra. The Shabara mantras which just look like some meaningless sentences are also mantras.